# Installation SharePoint Server 2013 on Windows 8.1

Tags: sharepoint, windows-8.1, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to install SharePoint Server 2013 on Windows 8.1 using [this guide](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2014/08/21/guest-blog-by-jonas-nilsson-install-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-7-8-8-1.aspx), but all my tries are failed.

Error from log file:

> 2015/07/03 19:57:50:376::[4056] Executing command path: 'C:\Program
> Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
> Extensions\15\BIN\stsadm.exe', args: '-o mergejsstrings -lcid 1049'
>
> 2015/07/03 19:57:50:376::[4056] Starting C:\Program Files\Common
> Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN\stsadm.exe -o
> mergejsstrings -lcid 1049
>
> 2015/07/03 19:57:53:303::[4056] Error:
> Command: 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
> Extensions\15\BIN\stsadm.exe' failed with error code: -532462766.
> Type: 8::CommandFailed.

PS My system is completely clean (Windows 8.1 with latest updates and sharepoint prerequisite only).

Answer (score 0):

This error is indicating that the installer isn't able to add new domains to your IIS installation. Unfortunately there's little more on offer than that as this is very far removed from the best practice approach for SharePoint (and strongly advised against).

If you wanted to do this to best practice (for local development) I would create a Hyper-V instance with Windows Server installed and install SharePoint server onto that, anything else should be for educational use only. [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869.aspx) Microsoft's documentation on the subject.

Comment: How can i use SharePoint Designer 2013 with SharePoint Server 2013 installed on Hyper-V Windows Server 2012 R2?